# deleted photo is still there in egophotoviewer

Tags: iphone, uitableview

when I delete images from tablecells in `UITableView` it use to get delete from tablecells as well as from server but when we click to open the other image in egophotoviewer the deleted image is still coming?..

Here is my code.

```
- (void)showSelectedPhoto:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSString *passingImageName = [[self.tableDataSource objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"fileName"];
    NSMutableArray *photoArray = [self getFilteredArray];
    NSMutableArray *urlsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (NSString *string in photoArray) {
        NSLog(@"String Values:%@", string);
        NSURL *imageUrl = [self getEnlargedImageImageUrl:[self._prefix stringByAppendingString:string]];
        NSLog(@"Passing url is:%@", imageUrl);
        photo = [[EGOQuickPhoto alloc] initWithImageURL:imageUrl name:string];
        [urlsArray addObject:photo];
    }
    if (!source) {
        self.source = [[EGOQuickPhotoSource alloc] initWithPhotos:urlsArray];
    }
    photoController = [[EGOPhotoViewController alloc] initWithPhotoSource:source];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:photoController animated:YES];
    NSUInteger index = [photoArray indexOfObject:passingImageName];
    [photoController moveToPhotoAtIndex:index animated:NO];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After deleting the image you need to reload the tableview.

```
 [tableView reloadData];
```

Comment: yeah i got it...i removed the if condition and simply write this self.source = [[EGOQuickPhotoSource alloc] initWithPhotos:urlsArray];